# Woo-commerce Checkout Summarized in Pop-up Card Entry Only

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Site URL: https://pamperingbear.org

Hi there, thanks for stopping in!

I am working on a project for a non-profit, donating my time and efforts, yet still want to deliver the best solution possible, that includes using the Divi theme!

Working with the 'Charity' layout from the library, on the landing page there is a module towards the top that has a donation amount and a submit button, it is currently using a contact form module and of course the submit button does not open the payment gateway, but boy, that would be great.

My goal is to keep the type of module as is there and clicking submits open the payment gateway module from WooCommerce, bypassing the shipping or address fields in a popup, allowing the user to simply enter their payment method and submit it right there. Can anyone suggest a method for this.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Hi Lucent, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins such as Woocommerce off-topic so you might notice some down-votes. That said, you may receive answers nevertheless. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).